# Issue in search function using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I try to bold the search word in a sentence by using the Regex.

```
String sentence = “help me subString in regexhelp. “
String  searchWord=”help”;

sentence.replaceAll("(^|\\s)(" + "(?i)" + searchWord + ")(\\s|$)", "$1<b>$2</b>$3");
```

Output:  **help** me subString in regexhelp.

Expected output:  **help** me subString in regex**help**

I want to bold all the matching string weather is it a string or substring.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you need to remove the preceding `(^|\\s)(` and following `")(\\s|$)"` patterns from your regex, because your current regex will match the string `help` only if it's preceded by  start of the line anchor or space and followed by end of the line anchor or space. Inorder to match also the substring `help`, you need to remove those patterns from your regex.

```
String sentence = "help me subString in regexhelp. ";
String  searchWord = "help";
System.out.println(sentence.replaceAll("(?i)(" + searchWord + ")", "<b>$1</b>"));
```

Output:

```
<b>help</b> me subString in regex<b>help</b>.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(help)
```

or in your case

```
"("+"(?i)"+searchWord+")"
```

Simply try this and replace by `<b>$1</b>`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/25